# xenprof: Initialization failed. Intel Processor Model 45 for P6 class family is not supported

Tags: linux, architecture, kernel, processor, xen

For some reasons I need to Xen 3.4 on the new server. But the machine could not load the kernel, giving the kernel Panic warning that "xenprof: Initialization failed. Intel Processor Model 45 for P6 class family is not supported."

My xen is 3.4 and linux kernel version is 2.6.18. The server processor is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 0 @ 2.40GHz, model 45.

This post (http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2011-06/msg02104.html) mentions that we can backport the processor support patches from latest xen 4.0 to the lower version. My question is (1) how did I do that? (2) Where do I find those patches?

Thanks!